# Como automatizar o login no Gmail?

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, delphi-7, gmail

## Explicação:

Atualmente, tenho uma URL que informa o Email de utilizador do Gmail:

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?+continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fgmail&service=mail&Email=**EMAIL**&Passwd=**senha**&null=Sign+in

Porém desta forma, a **Senha** não é carregada, apenas o **Email**.

## Objetivo:

Gostaria de um link no qual eu possa informar o Email e a senha, e em seguida realize o login automaticamente.

Se isto não for possível gostaria de uma solução alternativa.

Comment: Você quer carregar o email no seu site? Ou você quer requisitar as informações do email?
Não bastaria utilizar um `iframe`?

Comment: Isso não é possível. A Google não permitiria uma falha de segurança tão grande.
O ideal é usar as bibliotecas ou API disponíveis na linguagem que está usando no projeto.
Qual é o seu objetivo final com isso?

Comment: Nem um `<iframe>` adiantaria, @FelipeAvelar: é claro que o GMail bloqueiaria isso pois isso causaria falhas a segurança do sistema (sem contar termos de uso e outros  *yadda-yadda* que ninguém lê).

Comment: @matheus Vai que ele quer fazer um bookmark para entrar no e-mail sem ter que digitar a senha. Objetivos são vários e APIs talvez até desnecessárias: se só ele for usar, uma extensão serve, embora seja bem inseguro. Se for algo melhor ele vai acabar precisando fazer um cliente de e-mail (ou usar um).

Comment: Não é possível. O GMail não aceita senhas pela querystring. Também não adianta mandar cookies, tokens ou qualquer outra forma de fazer outra pessoa logar como você na máquina dela. A pessoa vai ter que digitar a senha de alguma forma em algum lugar.

Comment: Aliás, se fosse possível fazer o que você quer, o Google não poderia ser fonte de autenticação do OpenID ;)

Comment: @matheus Utilizo um gerenciador de e-mail com o Delphi, e meu objetivo é após enviar o e-mail logar a conta do Gmail no qual foi enviado o e-mail.

Comment: Por que não acessar por IMAP simplesmente?

Comment: Voce pode conseguir isso se vc usar uma aplicação por exemplo, um C# com um WebBrowser controller (WebKit ou IExplore). Desta forma voce pode manipular o navegador para fazer a autenticação automatica no GMail com base em dados do seu aplicativo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um servidor em java ou C++ que faça o papel de um Proxy para o conteúdo do e-mail desejado. Este servidor deve usar as APIs do Google para se conectar ao serviço de e-mail. Sua página WEB pode se comunicar com este servidor usando WebSocket, JSONP, ou AJAX com CORS habilitado e neste caso a requisição para este Proxy pode ter o formato que você desejar desde que você traduza para os comandos da API do google.

Nesta abordagem o cliente deve confiar em você e na sua arquitetura quando passar a senha pois você poderia armazená-la quebrando a segurança, mas isso pode ser negociável.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente existe uma alternativa melhor pois o Google disponibilizou uma plataforma para programação de Scripts para rodar como aplicação WEB ou ligada a documentos do Google Drive. Esta solução se chama `Google Apps Script` e está disponível em https://script.google.com.

Veja exemplo abaixo:

```
function doGet() {
    var app = buildApp();
    return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

    var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
    label.setVisible(true);

    app.close();

    return app;
}

function buildApp() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    app.setTitle('criando aplicação')
    var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
    app.add(button);

    var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.').setId('statusLabel')
        .setVisible(false);
    app.add(label);

    var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
    handler.addCallbackElement(label);
    button.addClickHandler(handler);

    app.setTitle('aplicação criada com id ' + app.getId());

    return app;
}
```

Você pode ver nesse [DOC](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E03-kZm36veATxMZPb6xI-e32oZ1kfi5ycUw_SRCehA/edit?usp=sharing) que redigi mais alguns detalhes.

Esta abordagem é melhor que a que sugeri anteriormente pois o  `Google Apps Script` permite interagir diretamente com o GMail e com toda a infraestrutura de Cloud do Google.